# Simplify SQL UNION Query

Tags: sql, left-join, union

I have actually three tables. They are categories, users and userCategories. As you can see a user can be assigned to multiple categories through the m-n userCategories table.

I want to select all categories for a specific user. If the category is assigned to that given user, the userFk-column should be the userId (for example 5), otherwise NULL.

I've got a similar result with this query. But is there a way to simplify this query?

```
select * 
from (
  SELECT `categoryId`, `category`, userFk FROM `category` c
  left join usercategories uc on c.categoryId = uc.catFk
  where userFk = 5
 union
  SELECT `categoryId`, `category`, userFk FROM `category` c
  left join usercategories uc on c.categoryId = uc.catFk
  where userFk != 5 OR userFk is NULL
) as result
group by categoryId
```

Comment: Well.. For example, if a category is assigned to user 2 & 5 and I say group by categoryId.. then I might lose the row which is assigned to user 5. Do you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the userid in the left join clause, it would save you the union

```
SELECT `categoryId`, `category`, userFk 
FROM `category` c
LEFT JOIN usercategories uc on c.categoryId = uc.catFk AND userFk = 5
```

That way, the only possible outcome of the query would be `userFK=5` or `NULL`, thus saving you the WHERE clause too.

Since the categories your user doesn't have can only show up once in a `userFK = NULL` tuple, you don't need the `group by` either, unless there's some repetition I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the categories of a user you could use:

```
SELECT `categoryId`, `category`, userFk FROM `category` c
left join usercategories uc on c.categoryId = uc.catFk
where userFk = 5
```

I suppose userCategories has no null values, a user without categories should not be in userCategories table.

Answer (score 0):

In the subquery the two parts of the union are the same apart from the where clause. All records of the subquery will fall in either of the two conditions, so isn't

```
SELECT `categoryId`, `category`, userFk FROM `category` c
left join usercategories uc on c.categoryId = uc.catFk
where userFk = 5
union
SELECT `categoryId`, `category`, userFk FROM `category` c
left join usercategories uc on c.categoryId = uc.catFk
where userFk != 5 OR userFk is NULL
```

equivalent to just

```
SELECT `categoryId`, `category`, userFk FROM `category` c
left join usercategories uc on c.categoryId = uc.catFk
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yes. I am afraid.. That will show duplicate results.. If you select a user in my application, I wanted to show the categories with check-marks and X-Cross, which indicate the assignment.